# Visual studio designer view cannot get correct form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

i have GUI project in C#. the main window class' definition looks like this:

FormView.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RssReader
{
    partial class FormView : Form, IView
    {
        private SplitContainer MainContainer;
        private TreeView Items;
        private MenuStrip MainMenu;
        private ToolStripMenuItem File;
        private ToolStripMenuItem AddFeed;
        private ToolStripSeparator Separator;
        private ToolStripMenuItem Quit;
        private WebBrowser Message;

        /* some methods here which are implementing some kind of logic */
    } 
}
```

FormViewInit.cs file

```
namespace RssReader
{
    partial class FormView
    {
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.MainContainer = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
            this.Items = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
            this.Message = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            this.MainMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.File = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.AddFeed = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.Separator = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.Quit = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();

            // the only component in this file is InitializeComponent method
            // all, what it does is just defining items on the form
            // and initializing it, i.e., creating instances, assign names etc.
        }
    }
}
```

FormViewEventHandlers.cs file

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RssReader
{
    partial class FormView
    {

        private void Quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to quit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                == DialogResult.Yes)
                Application.Exit();
        }

        // here goes event handler functions
    }
}
```

the question is: why i'm getting a form, with wrong size and no elements when i'm trying to view FormView.cs in design view in visual studio 2010?

Comment: I strongly suggest you start from a "normal" form, then change it little by little into what you need, checking each time whether you've broken the designer.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds to me like your InitializeComponet class is not setting the right values for your Form and its child controls properly (sounds like you're even missing the code that adds your elements to your Form). The Designer can do a lot of this work for you.

Comment: code, that set right values for form and it's children is set properly. i can run the application, and it works as expected. the only thing that i cannot view my application in designer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by moving elements definition into FormViewInit.cs file (file with InitializeComponent method).

how files looked before look in question. how file looks now:

```
public partial class FormView
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    private SplitContainer MainContainer;
    private TreeView Items;
    private MenuStrip MainMenu;
    private ToolStripMenuItem File;
    private ToolStripMenuItem AddFeed;
    private ToolStripSeparator Separator;
    private ToolStripMenuItem Quit;
    private ContextMenuStrip ContextMenu;
    private ToolStripMenuItem RemoveItem;
    private WebBrowser Message;

    protected void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.MainContainer = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.Items = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
        this.Message = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        this.MainMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
        this.File = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.AddFeed = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.Separator = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
        this.Quit = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.ContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
        this.RemoveItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.MainContainer.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.MainContainer.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.MainContainer.SuspendLayout();
        this.MainMenu.SuspendLayout();
        this.ContextMenu.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        /*  there goes properties initializing, like setting names, sizes etc  */
    }

    // Added just in case

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

you should view in designer mode FormViewInit.cs file, not FormView.cs

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a constructor in your FormView? If yes, is the method InitializeComponent() called?

Comment: class FormView has public constructor and i'm calling to method InitializeComponent().

Comment: Is it a default constructor? `public FormView(){...}`?

Comment: it's look like public FormView() { /* here goes some logic */ this.InitializeComponent(); }

Answer (score 0):

The form needs to be a `public` class.

Comment: i have added public keyword in all 3 files, but that didn't help.